# GridBagLayout shrink the menubar

Tags: java, gridbaglayout

Im using GridBagLayout just in the "contentPanel" to add the Menubar, CentralPanel and the StatusBar(Red in the end)

but after i add a scrollbar in another cardlayout that are added in the CentralPane, i dont know why, but it hide the menubar, there is a way to deal with it or another LayoutManager that i can do like the correct image?

[image: Here is the Correct one showing the menubar]

[image: If i add or resize the screen, the menubar hide :(]

Comment: Post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for better help sooner

Comment: I can't tell from your question, but you don't use the add method to add the JMenuBar to the JFrame.  You use the setJMenuBar method to add the JMenuBar to the JFrame.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the menu bar's minimum height e.g:

```
menuBar.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 30));
```

Seems that the menu bar doesn't have a pack() or other way of determining it's size, that is compatible with variable size layout managers.

Answer (score 0):

GridBagLayout is a sophisticated, flexible layout manager. In this case it's quite a bit too sophisticated, a simple [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) would do the job.